# React leaflet server-side rendering error: document is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

i has a react project with leaflet built in it, and i'm trying to run a server side for it.

I downloaded everything I needed, but as soon as I try to run the server using the command:
`node server/index.js`
I just get the following rendering error which redirects me to the `leaflet-src.js` file from the `dist` folder:

```
var style $ 1 = document.documentElement.style; 
ReferenceError: document is not defined
```

It is important to clarify that the application itself works,
but for some reason the server side doesn't agree to run...

does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: document is something that exists in browser not on server

Comment: ok... But this is what happens every time I try to start the server with the command i mentioned above, so what...?